# Did Ezra abrogate the Mosaic Law in Num. xviii. 21,(according to Yeb. 86b, Ḥul. 131b)?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, rabbis, oral-torah, ezra-the-scribe

According to  http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/636-abrogation-of-laws

The ancient rabbis claimed authority, not only to make new provisions and to establish institutions as a "hedge" for the protection of the Biblical laws, but under certain circumstances even to suspend and to abrogate a Biblical law.

the following cases of the abrogation of a Biblical law as stated in the Talmud: Ezra (according to [Yeb. 86b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.86b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Ḥul. 131b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.131b.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) decreed that the first tithe should be given to the priests, contrary to the Mosaic Law in [Num. xviii. 21](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.18.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), which ordained that they should be given to the Levites. In consequence of this abrogation another law had to be abrogated, namely, that which referred to the solemn profession which, according to [Deut. xxvi. 12-15](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.26.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), every farmer had to make annually in the Temple; for the passage in this confession, "have given it [the tithes] to the Levite," could not any longer be said in truth ([Soṭah, 47b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.47b.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), after Tosef., Sotah, xiii. 10).

The Prosbul.
Hillel the Elder enacted a measure, termed Prosbul, which was tantamount to an abrogation of the Biblical law in [Deut. xv. 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.15.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), concerning the release from debt in the Sabbatical year. Finding that this law, which was intended to benefit the poor, proved in the course of time rather a disadvantage to them, as no one was willing to lend them money lest he lose his claim at the approach of the Sabbatical year, Hillel, by virtue of his authority as head of the Sanhedrin, caused a law to be enactedby which the creditor could transfer the debt to the court in writing, so that the latter might collect it in spite of the Sabbatical year ([Mishnah Sheb. x. 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sheviit.10.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sheviit.10.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Have the previous Jewish religious authorities violated the Torah when they abrogated and changed some of its laws, e.g., "the previous 2 cases"?

Answer (score 3):

No. Neither of them was an abrogation of Torah law.

They  always could have been done in accordance with Torah law. The weren't done due to the lack of a pressing reason to do so.

Ezra never decreed that the first tithe should be given to the priests, contrary to the Torah which says that they should be given to the Levites. Rather the priests are ALSO Levites and referred to as such in many places in the Torah.They were ALWAYS entitled to the first tithe. Ezra penalized the non priest levites by making the rule that the first tithe should ONlY be given to levites who are also priests.

Similarly with regard to pruzbal.It   transfers the ownership of the debts to Beis Din and since it isn't a personal debt it is collectable even after Shemittah (see Makkos 3B) There are other explanations of the mechanism but according to all of them it works through pre-existing valid halachic principles. No laws were changed or undone to create it.

Comment: Basically -- they recommended people avail themselves of the existing loopholes.